# Telegram Login responds with "NOT_AUTHORIZED"

Tags: telegram

I am trying to use the Telegram Login Widget.

I have inserted the following script in my login page:

```
<script async="" src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?4" data-telegram-login="<name of bot>" data-size="large" data-auth-url="http://local.<domain>/tg" data-radius="0" data-request-access="write"></script>
```

This works insofar that the Login Widget gets displayed.

When I click the "Login with Telegram" button, it correctly asks me to Accept/Decline if I want to login at this website. But then nothing further happens.

By investigating the network requests I found that the telegram servers respond thus:

```
{"error":"NOT_AUTHORIZED","html":"<button class=\"btn tgme_widget_login_button\" onclick=\"return TWidgetLogin.auth();\"><i class=\"tgme_widget_login_button_icon\"><\/i>Log in with Telegram<\/button>","origin":"http:\/\/local.<domain>"}
```

Is there anything I am missing that I should have done?

I did have a chat with the @BotFather to set the domain to `http://local.<domain>`.

When logging in, I also get a message from Telegram in the Client telling me:

> You have successfully logged in on local.furry.cafe via @.
>   The website received your name, username and profile picture.

Things that could be problematic:

- `local.<domain>` is part of my /etc/hosts, but this shouldn't be a problem right?
- I don't use HTTPS on my dev machine? But this is not written as a requirement anywhere.

Comment: The problem is probably the local mapped domain.
Try with ngrok https://ngrok.com/

Comment: Since I own the domain, could I just make `local.<domain>` resolve to localhost? Would that fix it? Or what does Telegram actually try here?

Comment: I have tried it with ngrok, changed the domain etc, but I still get the same error (just with the ngrok domain)

Comment: I have added that I get a message from Telegram in the client which tells me it was successful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After several hours of more debugging I've found the reason:

**You need to have third-party cookies set as allowed**.

Since the request seems to be made from the asking window, it didn't have any authentication cookies attached, which in turn gave the `NOT_AUTHORIZED` response, while at the same time 'logging' you in, in the telegram client.

Since the server has no idea that the cookies was not set, it could not say anything.

TL;DR: Don't disable third party cookies if you want to use Telegram Login as a User.

I'll have to add a small text explanation so that if a user does have them disabled, it is shown to them.